# Pearl, Causality: what are variables and functional relationship?

Tags: probability, causality

In Pearl "Causality: Models...", he defines Causal Structure in (2.2.1) in terms of "variables" and "functional relationships".  This language conflicts with standard mathematical language where a functional is a map from either a vector space or a function to a field like $\mathbb{R}$.  I can guess that a random variable is a map from an event space to $\mathbb{R}$.

Can someone please explain what he means in terms of sets and functions?

Comment: The functional relationship is like a predictive model but for the counterfactual. Rubin's term for this was potential outcomes. Mathematically it's like a conditional mean model, except that the causal variables themselves are a network. Does that answer your question? What is the conflict that you perceive?

Comment: @AdamO  Could this be broken down into sets and functions?  That is the basic language of mathematics.

Comment: The RHS would be a probability model for the potential outcome--which is a set and a function. The LHS would be a possibly complex non-linear combination of covariates. Read about some models like GAMs for a sense of just how complex they can be. The idea behind Pearl's writing is (quoting him) "to exonerate [himself] from the actual specification and identification of such models".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are conflating the *adjective* functional with the *noun* functional.  In this particular quote, functional relationship simply means an arbitrary function.

As you said, a *functional* (substantive) is a special name for a particular type of mapping, for instance, when the domain is a space of functions and the range is the real line. Functionals show up a lot in causal inference as well. Estimands, like $\sum_{z}P(y|x, z)P(z)$, for instance, are  functionals --- they assign a real number to any observed joint probability distribution $P(y, x, z)$ (a function).

You can see [this use of functionals here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/324442/is-there-a-mathematical-definition-of-non-collapsibility/324587#324587) which also shows up in Causality, p. 193.